# Some Java classes are not uploaded during deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I just added three new classes to my application; they're very similar to existing ones. The functionality works in the dev environment, but not live: at least one class is missing from the deploy. It (like many others) is loaded via Class.forName and newInstance.

I see the .class files in the staging directory, but once deployed the app throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException when it tries to load it.

Are there limits to the number of classes in a package or something?

Comment: No, there are no limits. There is something wrong with the packaging. How is it done? Ant.. Maven??? Also did you make sure that the classes were missing my unpackaging the deployed .jar/.war.

Comment: Eclipse plugin. Where can I find the .jar/.war to unpack?

Comment: The time you reported the problem coincides with http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-downtime-notify/browse_thread/thread/13ad26a8c5ed7047/0f3eb0f8bae5678f?show_docid=0f3eb0f8bae5678f so you may have just been unlucky. What happens if you try to deploy now?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your build script is malfunctioning.

However there are limits.

> - maximum total number of files (app files and static files):     3,000
> - maximum size of an application file:    10 megabytes
> - maximum size of a static file:  10 megabytes
> - maximum total size of all application and static files:     150 megabytes

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse deploy functionality, and I'm nowhere near those limits.

Comment: Where did you get these limits from?

Comment: I got them here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits

Comment: The deploy process will let you know if you've hit these limits, though.